# A couple quick questions about handling image uploads in MVC 2

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I have a couple of simple questions about how to handle image uploads in ASP.NET MVC 2:

1. What would I put for their incoming types?  I want to bind to a custom edit model, so I'm not sure if I simply need to use `byte[]` parameters, or something more specific.
2. Do I need to store their MIME types along side them?  If so, how would I obtain that through the upload process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx). You should use `HttpPostedFileBase` instead of `byte[]`.
2. Yes, you need to store the MIME type unless you perform some conversion when those images are uploaded to the same image type or you will not be able to serve them later.